# Count number of pixels a string needs

Tags: kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

I want to be able to set the width of DataGrid cells, based on the number of pixels each string needs (they do not need to be the same size). I have not come across this on Google so was wondering if it was possible, based on the default font etc. used by TornadoFX. I imagine the library somewhere is keeping track of this

Answer (score 0):

I use `Text(yourStringHere).boundsInLocal.width + 12` to get semi-accurate results for text length. If I recall correctly, this requires the view/node to dock so a `runLater` call may be necessary. Also, the 12 offset was simply the number I needed to mimic a label's width and avoid cutoffs. It may be a different number for your use. I also did not test this to see if this scales appropriately in larger strings.